# iOS move UIAlertAction higher to top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am currently trying to add an alert with 3 textFields in it. I added multiple \n in the message in order to make the UIAlertController bigger. However, when the keyboard comes up, it blocks the ok and cancel buttons. As a result, I would like to know if there is a way to move the UIAlertController higher on the screen to prevent the buttons from being blocked.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.view.addSubview(textField1)
    alert.view.addSubview(textField2)
    alert.view.addSubview(textField3)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (_) in
        //
    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (_) in
        //
    }
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Comment: sounds to me like you need to rethink your UI/UX for this feature

Comment: Hmm yeah you're right. My textFields are already in the main view; I just wanted to avoid having a submit button in the main view, which is why I wanted everything in the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAlertController` contains `addTextField(configurationHandler: ((UITextField) -> Void)?` property you can directly use the textfields, for e.g you can use like as follow

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter First Name"
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Second Name"
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Third Name"
    }
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
        let firstTextField = alertController.textFields?.first as! UITextField
        let secondTextField = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
        let thirdTextField = alertController.textFields?.last as! UITextField
          print("firstName \(firstTextField.text), secondName \(secondTextField.text),thirdName \(thirdTextField.text)" )
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for example you get the sample tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/@chan.henryk/alert-controller-with-text-field-in-swift-3-bda7ac06026c)

Comment: Looks like I can't actually do this, because of other reasons in my UI. But that's on me for leaving those details out. This is the correct answer based on what I asked. As suggested by Brian Ogden, I'll fix my UI/UX.